# c# delegate that references and adds to itself

Tags: c#, lambda

When I run this code:

```
string x = "";
Action<int> myAction = (i) => x += ("A" + i);
myAction = (i) =>
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        x += ("B" + i);
        myAction += (i2) => x += ("C" + i + i2);
        myAction(i - 1);
    }
};
myAction(3);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

What prints is:
B3B2B1C30C20C10C31C21C32

Can anyone give me an explanation as to why this gets printed?

Comment: Just step through the code with a debugger, and see what happens line by line.

Comment: Even when I go through the debugger, it is still confusing why the code goes through the order it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that as soon as you do:

```
myAction = ....
```

you can **forget** about what you previously set `myAction` to; that is now lost to the ether. You might as well have initialized `Action<int> myAction = null;`. The key point is that the *variable* `myAction` is captured - not the *value* of it. Thus, the code inside the second delegate is *calling itself*, not the code that involved "A".

Likewise, when you do `myAction += (i2) => x += ("C" + i + i2);` - you are changing the delegate for all subsequent code.

Note also that local functions might be a better and clearer way to do this type of thing now.

---

Let's look at what actually happens; we start with:

```
myAction = (i) =>
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        x += ("B" + i);
        myAction += (i2) => x += ("C" + i + i2);
        myAction(i - 1);
    }
};
```

and call `myAction(3)`. `i>0`, so `x` becomes "B3". Now we do something complex - we combine two delegates, so `myAction` is now:

```
myAction = (i) =>
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        x += ("B" + i);
        myAction += (i2) => x += ("C" + i + i2);
        myAction(i - 1);
    }
} + (i2) => x += ("C" + i + i2);
```

(meaning, it runs one method then the other), and noting that `i` **in the second delegate** is the *parameter* `i` from the previous call. Since that parameter doesn't change, we can notionally fix it (although in reality it is a capture context field), and say that:

```
myAction = (i) =>
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        x += ("B" + i);
        myAction += (i2) => x += ("C" + i + i2);
        myAction(i - 1);
    }
} + (i2) => x += ("C" + 3 + i2);
```

Now we invoke `myAction(i - 1 === 2);`. Fine - let's execute the two pieces in turn; the first piece finds `i>0` so x becomes "B3B2". Now we rewrite `myAction`, making it a triple:

```
myAction = (i) =>
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        x += ("B" + i);
        myAction += (i2) => x += ("C" + i + i2);
        myAction(i - 1);
    }
} + (i2) => x += ("C" + 3 + i2)
  + (i2) => x += ("C" + 2 + i2);
```

(note I've fixed the value of the parameter like before), and we execute `myAction(i - 1)`.

Before we do that ... keep in the back of your head that we still have a pending `(i2) => x += ("C" + 3 + i2);` for `i2=2` to execute, but that comes later (we'll call that "PendingA" when I mention it later). This pending execution is not impacted by us assigning a new value to the delegate, since delegates are immutable.

So: `myAction(i-1 === 1)`: yet again, `i>0` so `x` becomes "B3B2B1", and we change the delegate *again*:

```
myAction = (i) =>
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        x += ("B" + i);
        myAction += (i2) => x += ("C" + i + i2);
        myAction(i - 1);
    }
} + (i2) => x += ("C" + 3 + i2)
  + (i2) => x += ("C" + 2 + i2);
  + (i2) => x += ("C" + 1 + i2);
```

(again, noting that I'm pinning the value). We *invoke* that with `myAction(i-1) === 0`, again first noting that we have a pending:

```
    (i2) => x += ("C" + 3 + i2)
  + (i2) => x += ("C" + 2 + i2); // call this PendingB
```

with `i2===1` to run later as we unroll.

The first part doesn't do anything, but we do have the three suffixes to run with `i2===0`; so we get (applying them in turn) "B3B2B1C30C20C10". And we're done with that - we've hit the bottom of the stack. Now we need to unroll! We have a pending double-footer to run. Unrolling, "PendingB" comes first, which makes `x` become "B3B2B1C30C20C10C31C21"; then "PendingA" gives us "B3B2B1C30C20C10C31C21C32"

Comment: This isn't actually answering the question.  This doesn't explain why what is printed, gets printed.

Comment: @Servy it does if the question is (which is what I'm implicitly reading) "how come it didn't output stuff involving 'A'?" - everything beyond that is stepping through that second delegate's code line by line, recursively; that isn't a useful thing for me to do

Comment: Yes, if the question were a completely different question than what was asked, you'd have answered it.  However, since the question *isn't* that completely different question that they didn't ask, no, you haven't answered it.  That you don't think answering the question is a useful thing to do doesn't mean that it's appropriate to post an answer that doesn't answer the question.  If you don't think answering the question is useful, then *don't answer it*.

Comment: @Servy I think we simply disagree on whether or not I'm answering it; please don't say things like "That you don't think answering the question is a useful thing to do doesn't mean..." - that is completely disingenuous and completely misrepresents my intentions. Please feel free to add what **you** consider to be a great answer, by: posting an answer.

Comment: This is a little helpful, but I still have questions on why all of the B's are executed before all of the C's, and why the C's are outputted in the order they are.

Comment: @DrewCottrill k... I'll extend my answer a bit

Comment: @DrewCottrill here you go... try that

Comment: @Servy any better?

Comment: Yes, much better. Thanks!